# AppleScript: how to open the terminal fullscreen and execute commands

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, script, fullscreen

I need an applescript, which can do the job below:

- open the application Terminal with fullscreen
- run some scripts

Here is what I've tried:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    tell window 1
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}    
        end tell
        do script "cd Documents/'cpp project'/test3" in window 1
        do script "./matrix.out" in window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: In the future if you are having problems with a script, please be explicit about _what's wrong_ and any error messages you encountered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be talking to Terminal, not `window 1`. This script worked fine for me.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
    end tell
    do script "cd ~/Downloads" in window 1
    do script "brew list" in window 1
end tell
```